# d3 linear domain nice values

Tags: javascript, d3.js

is there a way in d3 to get nice linear values?
I want to visualize a value between 0 and 50.000 and I want the scale to change only on certain intervals.

right now my code looks like:

```
_yMax = function(maxValue){
    if(maxValue < 4000){return 5000;}
    if(maxValue < 9000){return 10000;}
    if(maxValue < 22000){return 25000;}
    if(maxValue < 45000){return 50000;}
    return maxValue;
 }
```

I would prefer code that scales if my value goes beyond 50.000. I wonder if it is possible to make a nice round function.

basically I would like to use `d3.scale.linear.nice` but for large integers

Comment: You could divide your large values by a suitable factor and then call `.nice()`.